# copy list item to another sharepoint list so that it is in both lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow, copy-item

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I am working on 2 sharepoint lists, and I have a flow set up between them so that when an item is created/modified for list 1 it is copied over to list 2. however the items I am creating on list 1 are not there, they are only showing up on list 2.

So list 1 is blank and and list 2 has the items that were created on list 1.

How can I edit my flow so that the items are populated in both list 1 and list 2?

[image: my flow]

EWO app is list 1 and EWO for maintenance is list 2.

Answer (score 0):

For your flow, the actions may be better like this:
[image]

When a new item is created in list A, use get item action to get all properties of that item in list A. Then create the new item in list B with all the properties you just get. Then delete the item in List A.

Comment: Hey Jerry, I want to keep the items in List B and List A

Comment: @JessicaBarfield， Then remove the delete item action. In fact you can also try Matiur's approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how I would accomplish this:**

1. When an item is created in the *Primary* list, created a new item in the *Secondary* list
2. When an item is updated in the *Primary* list, update the corresponding item in the *Secondary* list

In order to update the Secondary list, I would add a number column, say **PrimaryListID**, in the *Secondary* list to store the ID of the item created in the Primary list. This helps to get items from the Secondary list for updating.

**The MS Flow screenshots are shown below**:
[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]